# how to use health kit sample query in progressive ways

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, healthkit, hksamplequery

I really want the results from executing a `HKSampleQuery`. But, I always cannot get the results right after executing the query.

My case is below (error processing code is deleted):

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)

// get the latest step count sample
let stepSampleQuery: HKSampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: (stepCountQty)!,
    predicate: nil,
    limit: 1,
    sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) {
        (query, results, error) -> Void in

        if let result = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
            // result[0] is the sample what I want
            self.lastStepDate = result[0].startDate
            print("readLastStep: ", self.lastStepDate)
        }
}
self.healthStore.executeQuery(query)
// now, I want to use the "self.lastStepDate"
// But, I cannot get the appropriate value of the variable.
```

I don't think the code run progressively. When does `resultHandler` of `HKSampleQuery` run? I really want the handler code to run before I use the results from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `resultsHandler` runs is documented in the [HKSampleQuery reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSampleQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKSampleQuery/initWithSampleType:predicate:limit:sortDescriptors:resultsHandler:):

> After instantiating the query, call the HKHealthStore class’s
>   executeQuery: method to run this query. Queries run on an anonymous
>   background queue. As soon as the query is complete, the results
>   handler is executed on the background queue. You typically dispatch
>   these results to the main queue to update the user interface.

Since the query is performed asynchronously, you should perform work that depends on the results of the query in response to `resultsHandler` being called.  For instance you could do the following:

```
// get the latest step count sample
let stepSampleQuery: HKSampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: (stepCountQty)!,
    predicate: nil,
    limit: 1,
    sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) {
        (query, results, error) -> Void in

        if let result = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
            // result[0] is the sample what I want
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               self.lastStepDate = result[0].startDate
               print("readLastStep: ", self.lastStepDate)

               self.doSomethingWithLastStepDate()
            }
        }
}
self.healthStore.executeQuery(query)
```

Note that since the handler gets called on a background queue, I've done the work related to `lastStepDate` on the main queue to avoid synchronization issues.

Comment: But, I will use the variable in an observer query, which will be executed in the background. I know HKSampleQuery cannot be executed in the background.
If I wrote the code about the observer query in the space `self.doSomethingWithLastStepDate`, I think the observer query cannot be used in the background

Comment: I want my app to run in background. An observer query in my app is detecting new samples in HealthKit store even in the background.
When the observer query got to know some samples are added, my app should compare last step date and current date.

Comment: There is nothing preventing queries from executing when your app is in the background.

Comment: An answer in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117630/does-the-appdelegate-initialize-when-healthkit-wakes-my-app-in-the-background) said "the updateHandler of the observer query you should initiate anther query"
But, your answer make me reverse it because your answer said my observer query should be in the sample query

Comment: `resultHandler` of HKSampleQuery cannot be executed in the background

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you weren't also using an observer query.  Still, you could just create your sample query and run it in response to the observer query firing.  The behavior of the the sample query remains the same, the results handler runs asynchronously so you have to design your code accordingly.

Comment: Yes.... I have tried my best to get information about using HKSampleQuery and HKObserverQuery simultaneously...  
The reference and documents in the internet said I should use HKSampleQuery in `updateHandler` of HKObserverQuery.  
But my case should use HKObserverQuery in `resultHandler` of HKSampleQuery...  
I don't know how to change my app design :(